# Aaron Hillegass :: [NSArrayController add] = insertObject method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I must be missing something.  I'm in the chapter titled "Key-Value Observing" in Cocoa Programming by Aaron Hillegass.

I have inserted the code that enables the application to undo/redo adding and subtracting employees from RaiseMan.  The application works however what I'm wondering is why is that when I link the "Add Employee" to the NSArrayController to the ADD method (using the .xib file) it calls

```
- (void)insertObject:(Person *)p inEmployeesAtIndex:(int)index;
```

According to the Key-Value Coding, shouldn't the add method call?

```
- (void)addEmployeesObject:newEmployee;
```

I'm linking the 'add' method not the 'insert' method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array controller is bound to an ordered collection (an array). That's why it uses `insertObject:inEmployeesAtIndex:` to add a new object at the end of the the collection.

The `addEmployeesObject:` method would be used if the collection was unordered (i.e. a set).

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior when using [KVC collection accessor methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-178830-BAJEDEFB). It's more efficient to insert an object at the desired location (even if that location is at the end) than to wonder if "it's at the end" and call -add... directly. All of this is *much* more efficient than, say, replacing the entire array with an entirely new (-setEmployees:, for example) array when the range of the modification is already known. NSArrayController ultimately uses this method when inserting an object into the array it's controlling.